# applying a function to each element in vector in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing some performance critical code..

```
def sig(x):
   return 1/(1+exp(x))
```

I have a vector

```
x = [.... say n elements]

transform_x = [sig(ele) for ele in x]

transform_x = map(lambda ele: sig(ele), x) # bit faster than above loop
```

But is there a better way to apply the function to achieve the above effect but maybe in vectorized way(which I presume should be better)?

Comment: As others answered, numpy has built in vectorized versions of common functions, including +, /, and exp.  You can also define your own vectorized functions, but those are generally the same speed as a for loop: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html.

Comment: I am not sure which `exp()` function you're using here, but I would say you should use `numpy.exp` then you can pass the whole array to the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just apply the function to the entire array, like you would in MATLAB:

```
transformed = sig(x)
```